# How to delete Duplicate rows from a table which are having same values for all the columns and without using window functions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

My Table is

```
+-----+----+----+------+
|EmpID|Name|Dept|Deptno|
+-----+----+----+------+
|1    |Abc |xyz |10    |
|1    |Abc |xyz |10    |
|2    |Def |pqr |20    |
+-----+----+----+------+
```

I want the output table as

```
+-----+----+----+------+
|EmpID|Name|Dept|Deptno|
+-----+----+----+------+
|1    |Abc |xyz |10    |
|2    |Def |pqr |20    |
+-----+----+----+------+
```

Conditions:

1. Don't Use window functions.
2. Table doesn't have any keys.
3. Don't Use Temporary Tables.

I tried a Query:

```
delete from table_name where EmpId IN (
select EmpID from table_name group by EmpId,Name,Email,Deptno having count(*)>1 )
```

But, this query deletes all the rows which are having count > 1.
But, I trying to delete the duplicate rows except one

Comment: Just to make sure. Do you have to delete that duplicates row from your table or do you want your output to have no duplicates?

Comment: Why those conditions?

Comment: @DenStudent Yea.. I want to delete the duplicates in the same table..

Comment: @jarlh Without those conditions, the problem is easy to solve. The real problem lies in conditions. I want to find other way of solving the problem accepting all the conditions.

Comment: Very similar to a teacher's request.

Comment: @jarlh What you mean by teacher's request?

Comment: How is this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/18949/5418176

Comment: @DenStudent I don't have any identity column.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CTE` + `ROW_NUMBER` to delete the duplicates alone

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Row_number()OVER(partition BY EmpId, Name, Email, Deptno ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn,*
         FROM   table_name)
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE  rn > 1
```

I think you can keep only `EmpId` in `Partition BY`

Comment: I know your answer before... But, I am trying to find other way without window functions...

Comment: @KurellaHemanth - DO you have  any other column which has different value

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
   SELECT EmpID,Name,Dept,Deptno,
       RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY EmpID,Name,Dept,Deptno ORDER BY EmpID,Name,Dept,Deptno)
   FROM MyTable     
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Apply Below 3 Query For Your Problem.

1.)
ALTER TABLE dbo.test ADD AUTOID INT IDENTITY(1,1)

2.)
SELECT * FROM dbo.test WHERE AUTOID NOT IN (SELECT MIN(AUTOID) _
FROM dbo.test GROUP BY EmpId,Name,dept,Deptno)

3.)
DELETE FROM dbo.test WHERE AUTOID NOT IN (SELECT MIN(AUTOID) _
FROM dbo.test GROUP BY EmpId,Name,dept,Deptno)

Comment: This is same like using Row_Number()... Any other way please??